# How to Clear All in all IntelliJ IDEA windows?

Tags: intellij-idea

I run Spring Boot apps in different IntelliJ IDEA windows and sometimes I have to follow a request through multiple micro-services. So I have to go to each Idea window and press Clear All.

Is there a command that clears logs in all instances of Idea at once?

Comment: there is a feature request, please upvote: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-221219